Is it possible to update the login email in a Telethon session?
Is it possible to update the login email in a Telethon session?
Hello everyone,
I’m working with Telethon and I want to know if there’s a way to update or change the login email for an existing session. Has anyone encountered this situation, or is it possible to achieve this? If so, could you please share how to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
